# Как можно узнать IP пользователей WIFI?

Tags: c#, ip, wifi, udp

С мобильного приложения нужно подключится к серверу на компьютере. Есть ли какой-то способ получить список устройств которые подключены к сети WIFI к которой подключено мобильное устройство? Я думал над тем чтобы брать первую часть IP своего устройства, к примеру от 192.168.0.100 взять 192.168.0, а дальше уже перебирать от 0 до 255 и надсылать каждому на порт данные, и если есть ответ то значит это он. Но не думаю что это лучшее решение.

Comment: С сервера получить или с мобильного?

Comment: @eri с мобильного, приложение на c#

Comment: Если mdns не хочешь, то бродкастом пошли. Но на бродкасте потери сильные обычно.

Comment: Есть ли смысл для mdns если в сети будет только 1 клиент 1 сервер и размер данных не большой(небольшие json словари) и иногда базы данных < 1 MB?

Comment: mdns это не транспорт, а только обнаружение. потом создаешь обычное юникаст соединение.

Comment: ещё глять https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP, похожая штука, но можно ещё и небольшую транспортную нагрузку накинуть. не раздел перенаправления портов, там ещё много чего есть

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Современное решение для обнаружения "своих" это мультикаст днс. Регистрируешь сервис в mdns, bonjour, avahi. Клиент запрашивает "у кого есть такой сервис" и получает список.